# SAX Parser in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xml-parsing, sax

I am parsing xml files in a folder using Python SAX Parser and writing the output in CSV using pandas, But I am getting only the data from last file in the CSV.

I am new to Python and this is for the first time trying SAX Parsing

File read:

```
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(fp1): 
          for filename in files:
            print(files)
            fname = os.path.join(dirpath,filename)
            if fname.endswith('.xml'):
              print(fname)
              #for count in files:
            parser.parse(fname)
```

```
 def characters(self, content):
        rows = []
        cols = ["ReporterCite","DecisionDate","CaseName","FileNum","CourtLocation","CourtName","CourtAbbrv","Judge","CaseLength","CourtCite","ParallelCite","CitedCount","UCN"]
        #ReporteCite, DecisionDate, CaseName, FileNum, CourtLocation, CourtName, CourtAbbrv, Judge, CaseLength, CourtCite, ParallelCite, CitedCount, UCN             

        rows.append({"ReporterCite":self.rc,
                     "DecisionDate": self.dd,
                     "CaseName": self.can,
                     "FileNum": self.fn,
                     "CourtLocation": self.loc,
                     "CourtName": self.cn,
                     "CourtAbbrv": self.ca,
                     "Judge": self.j,   
                     "CaseLength": self.cl,
                     "CourtCite": self.cc,
                     "ParallelCite": self.pc,
                     "CitedCount": self.cd,
                     "UCN": self.rn})

        #print(rows)
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
        df.to_csv(fp2,index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you will always overwrite your previous result. This is a pandas question, not a SAX question. You would like append to the existing csv, right? If this is the case you have to use the **mode = ‘a’**, like
`df.to_csv('filename.csv',mode = 'a')`
More options, see [Doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

- 'w'  open for writing, truncating the file first (default)
- 'x'  open for exclusive creation, failing if file already exists
- 'a'  open for writing, appending to the end of file if it exists

Comment: Thank you so much Paul. This is working just that I need to find a way to take care of the duplicates. Much appreciated